# C++ interface driven design - interfaces and tree

Tags: c++

I am trying to use interface driven principle, in a nutshell, it is like this, each real class implements several interface classes; namely the real class has no public API of its own.

In one package, all real classes are organized as a tree, so tree interface is common to all real classes:

```
class Node_I {
  public:
    virtual Node* get_parent() = 0;
    virtual vector<Node*> get_children() = 0;
    virtual string get_name() = 0;
};
```

Now comes to some tricky problem, different nodes have different behaviors, for example, trimable, printable, etc. Without going into the domain specifics, there are in total 7-8 interfaces. Now I have 2 choices:

```
1. Strictly follow the principle
```

I may have class like this:

```
class A: public Node_I, Trimable, Printable, Intf_X, Intf_Y, Intf_Z {};

class B: public Node_I, Intf_Y {};



 2. Merge the most command APIs to Node_I
```

For example, move printable API to Node_I and add some logic to non-printable nodes so that it tells the caller it is actually not printable.

1> is clean at design level and it is what I am doing, but after writing so many dynamic_cast, I begin to doubt if I am too much doctrine. Because one object can have multiple sibling-parents, I need to keep using dynamic_cast to switch from one role to another.

2> is not good either(I experimented a bit), the more I merge API to Node_I, the more dummy logic I have to add. Many class member functions end up either empty or one-liner. The problem is, if I do not merge API, they would not exist at all.

As puzzled as I am, not sure what is the right criteria here.

What is your experience?

Any great book/paper/article about interface driven design? Preferably in C++.

Comment: Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu is a phenomenal one, it might address what you want: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780201704310/samplepages/0201704315.pdf

Comment: My experience has been (generally) that method 1 is error prone, and dynamic_casts are slow. Method 2 is typically faster, but you have to think a-lot harder about the class structure. When I find myself looking into problem 1, i find that I'm not asking the polymorphism question correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313596/return-a-type-or-how-to-preserve-a-type-of-an-object-pointer/21315475#21315475