# Any-type holder with dynamic type casting

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement an object holder (similar to `boost::any`) with an additional feature that the objects could be accessed using their base class types. I understand that this is not possible simply using the `boost::any` class as one needs to know at any moment the precise type of the object when accessing it, e.g., to get a reference to the object stored in this "any" holder.

Currently, I'm solving this problem in a bit stupid way. I define a sort of conversion trait with which I can specify some base-derived type relations, e.g., as follows:

```
// By default, T is a base of itself.
template<typename T> struct conversion_trait
{
        typedef T base_type;
};

// Says that "base" is a base type of "derived".
template<> struct conversion_trait<derived>
{
        typedef base base_type;
};
```

The point is that, when instantiating a holder using the template constructor or using the template assignment operator, I actually create a holder using the base class type specified by the traits. When accessing the variable, I can then use both the base and derived type as specified by the traits.

For example, the template constructor looks like:

```
template<typename T> variable::variable(const rcp<T> &rhs)
: m_any(new any) // shared pointer having the any-holder: rcp<any>
{
    *m_any = rcp_dynamic_cast<typename conversion_trait<T>::base_type>(rhs);
}
```

Here, `any` is essentially something like `boost::any` and `rcp` is just an implementation of the reference counted pointers (much like `boost::shared_ptr` or that in STL of C++11, more or less). There are reasons why I need to keep the any holder in a shared pointer and why to have a shared pointer in that any holder.

The "getter" of the rcp pointer with content of the any holder looks (in a very simplified way) like:

```
template<typename T> rcp<T> variable::get_rcp()
{
    typedef typename conversion_trait<T>::base_type base_type;
    // First, get the content of the base type of T.
    // (templated get() is something like boost::any_cast)
    rcp<base_type> base = m_any->get<rcp<base_type>>();
    // Then do dynamic cast to T.
    return rcp_dynamic_cast<T>(base);
}
```

So now, if I store in the variable an instance of the type `derived`, I can access it using both `derived` and `base`. However, I need to specify this relation manually in a specialisation of the conversion trait.

Also, it might be a bit complicated, if the hierarchy was more complicated. If I has a hierarchy `abstract` base of `base` base of `derived`. It would still be doable, defining conversion trait for both `base` and `derived` to the `abstract` type, but it starts to get already a bit cumbersome.

> **Question:** Is there any kind of workaround to get the same functionality without the use of this explicit conversion and having a possibility to access the "any-holder" using any type?

I know about "[dynamic_any](https://github.com/bytemaster/Boost.DynamicAny/blob/master/include/boost/dynamic_any.hpp)" but I cannot use it because I cannot afford to make copies of the objects inside the holder (the copies are quite expensive).
The only other "solution" I can think of now uses templated virtual methods, which is of course impossible.

Thanks in advance for any pointer or suggestion.

Comment: Did you notice that amongst `boost::any` boost also provides a `boost::variant` type, that might fit better for your needs?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did but it requires the set of used types to be known a priori.

Comment: So...C++ is a strongly typed language with no (real) reflection. Trying to introduce a language feature (like dynamic typing) usually isn't a great idea. I've gone down the road you are going and I assure you it only contains madness. That being said, it is not immediately clear to me what is reference, what is pointer, and what is a concrete instance in your code. It looks to me like m_any->get<base_type>() either returns an rcp on its own, or rcp<base_type> is assignable from a reference?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams If I could I would use Python for this application which would be much more suitable. However, the original choice was C++ so this is the way I should follow :-) Thanks for the notice, it of course should be `m_any->get<rcp<base_type>>()` (typo).

Comment: Are all of the elements part of the same hierarchy? Other than that, you might want to describe the real problem that you want to solve, rather than the problems you ran into with your intended solution.

Comment: @UndefinedPavel So the problem is that you are trying to think in python to solve a problem in C++. What is the problem you are trying to solve? There is most likely a different design pattern to avoid this type of stuff than it being easy to add dynamic typic to a strongly typed language.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Not all. This is a part of a computational code and the elements can be matrices, vectors, and essentially whatever kind of classes. The reason why I'm doing this is that sometimes I would like to treat the matrices like matrices, sometimes like operators. The current solution works just fine, I'm only trying to verify if there is really not any better way to do this.

Comment: @UndefinedPavel You'd probably be better served with templates and template specialization to moc duck typing than trying to do what you are doing. "works just fine" looks ok, but maintaining this will be a beast, and dynamic_cast will add a ton of overhead that you don't want in your code.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I agree that using dynamic typing is madness. This is supposed to be a part of a sort of computational framework which would be in a sense driven by combining certain "black-boxes" specified in an input text file. So static typing is, as far as I can say, off the question for this purpose. Note that most of the work is done in the computational routines not the framework itself, so some overhead due to the use of RTTI should be negligible.

Comment: @UndefinedPavel see my answer here, i think it exposes the problem  nicely, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313596/return-a-type-or-how-to-preserve-a-type-of-an-object-pointer/21315475#21315475. Basically you are NOT using polymorphism, and if you were this wouldn't be a problem.